# HTML Multiple option Dropdown box + manual input

Tags: html, select, input

I need to have an HTML select with multiple selection capabilities. No problem until that, can use  and multiple. But additionally I want the user to manually input another option, think of the options like this:

---

Please choose at least 2 or Manually input:

- Option A
- Option B
- Option C
- Option D
- Option E
- Other (Please input)

---

Can this be done? or should I think of other methods like checkboxes and a text input?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5629435/1299995

Answer (score 0):

in case you want the user to input the other option him/herself, then you can use checkboxes and rather activate a textbox in case the user checks the "other" textbox. That is probably the way I would attempt do it.